# setting marker coordinates as variable

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-maps

I'm trying to get the `Lng` and `Lat` from the marker that I set on the google maps api.

I automatically want the coordinates to take place in my html form.

It looks like I'm not getting the `getPosition()` right, because every other variable I use (something like `var x = 34`) does work.

**My code:**

```html
  <form action="send_nieuwcontainer.php" method="post">
    Marker_name: <input type="text" name="markername"><br>
    Coördinaten: <br>
    Lng: <input id="inputlng" type="text" placeholder="<?php $lng; ?>" readonly="readonly">
    Lat: <input id="inputlat" type="text" placeholder="<?php $lat; ?>" readonly="readonly"><br>
  </form>
</div>

<script>
function initMap() {
  var groningen = {lat: 53.218883, lng:  6.566298};
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 12,
    center: groningen
  });

  map.addListener('click', function(e) {
    clearMarkers();
    addMarker(e.latLng, map);
  });

}

var markers = [];

var lng = marker.getPosition().lng();
var lat = marker.getPosition().lat();
document.getElementById('inputlng').value = lng;
document.getElementById('inputlat').value = lat;


// Adds a marker to the map.
function addMarker(latLng, map) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latLng,
    map: map
  });
  markers.push(marker);
  if (marker = true) {
    document.getElementById('replaceMe').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('replacement').style.visibility = 'visible';
  } else {
    alert ("Does not work");
  }
}
```

Does someone see what I'm doing wrong or maybe something I'm forgetting?

Note: I've already tried looking on stackoverflow and googlemaps api guide. They keep telling me to use `getPosition()`

Comment: Your `marker` is declared within a function using `var`. You can not access it outside of the function. It needs to be declared and initialised in the global scope _before_ you try to access it's properties.

Comment: What is `if (marker = true)` for? If you're trying to check if marker is a `marker`, not null, not undefined, you can simply use `if(marker)`.

Comment: I get a javascript error with your code: `Uncaught ReferenceError: clearMarkers is not defined`.  If I fix that I get a map.  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: My excuses @geocodezip, I'm new and I just wanted to get help. Will read rules before new post. For now here is my code: https://codeshare.io/aJAP6K

Answer (score 0):

As @Turnip said, the `marker` var is declared with `var` inside `addMarker`, so it's only accessible inside `addMarker`.

Try declaring `marker` outside the function like `var marker;` and then, inside the function, instead of using `var marker = ...`, use `marker = ...`.

Comment: I should have known this, but still when I create `var marker = [];` and inside the function as `marker = new google.maps.Marker(` after that I use `alert(lng)` inside `if(marker)` to test if it gets the coordinates but it still says "undefined"..

Comment: Where/when do you call `initMap()`? `marker` will still be undefined if `initMap()` hasn't run before you try to use `.getPosition()`

Comment: I do call `initMap()` before I try to use `getPosition()`. Still its undefined.. You can see the full code here: https://codeshare.io/aJAP6K